# nginx prevent location in ssl rewrite

Tags: nginx, ssl, rewrite

How do I prevent a location from being matched by the ssl rewrite?

```
server {
        listen      80;
        server_name example.net;

        location = /feeds/ {
                break;
        }

        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
        listen 443;
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rewrite in a location block. nginx only applies one location block at each level, so if `/feeds/` is matched the other block won't be applied:

```
location / {
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```